# Write a regular expression which catches user $HOME in shellscripting

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, regex

I'd like to write a `regex` in `shellscript` which would compare the user input path to user`$HOME`. Then it would raise an error in case the user input path contains the user `$HOME`. The home folder normally starts with `/ort/home` but `/ort` part is not a must. When I run it always gives a `valid path` although I clearly enter an invalid path. What am I doing wrong? Thanks. Please refer following link[1] if necessary to see how `regex` are used in `shellscript`

My attempt is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

function user_input () {

        read -p "Type the path for project1:" user_path

        string1="${HOME}"
        echo "$string1"

        if [ "$user_path" = "$string1 | /ort/home/+.* |  .*+/home/+.*"  ]; then 
             echo "Not a valid path, contains $HOME directory"        
        else
             echo "valid path"
        fi
}

function main() {

user_input
}

main
```

## Terminal output

Please note first entry is a valid path and other two are invalid paths.

```
jenny@server32:~$ ./test.sh 
Type the path for project1:/scratch/random
/ort/home/j/jen
valid path

jenny@server32:~$ ./test.sh 
Type the path for project1:/ort/home/j/jen
/ort/home/j/jen
valid path

jenny@server32:~$ ./test.sh 
Type the path for project1:/ort/home
/ort/home/j/jen
valid path
```

[1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash

Comment: Regular expression comparison and string (glob pattern) comparison are different things, with different operators in bash (`=~` versus `==` or `=`); additionally, `=~` is only supported within extended test brackets `[[ ... ]]` afaik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`case` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) uses [glob wildcards](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) which are pretty easy to work with:

```
case "$user_path" in
    "$HOME"*) echo "Error: path cannot be in your HOME" ;;
    */home/*) echo "Error: cannot have 'home' in the path" ;;
    *) echo "Thank you, valid path" ;;
esac
```